# Hello, how are you? Please can you tell me how I can put the period of months from December last year to November in a pivot table in Excel?

Tags: calendar

I want to visualize the sales in a pivot table in the financial year of the company starting from December last year to November.

Thanks, and regards,
John

I was trying to edit custom lists which is found in File - Options - Advanced - Edit Custom Lists Button, but I can only change the order of the months of the same year.